# NZEC for fibosum(spoj) in python

Tags: python

The code works perfectly fine on my interpreter but gives NZEC on spoj.

```
cases = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(cases):
    k = 0
    n,m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    sq5 = Decimal(sqrt(5))
    phi = (1 + sq5)/2                          #Refer wikipedia page for calculating fibonacci numbers
    print (int(Decimal(phi)**(m+2)/sq5 + Decimal(0.5)) - int(Decimal(phi)**(n+1)/sq5 + Decimal(0.5)))%1000000007
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrap the line `n,m = map(int,...` inside your for loop in a `try: n,m = map(int,... except: break`. Does this work?

Comment: No. It still gives NZEC.

Comment: The Fibonacci numbers you need for this problem are far too large to be stored accurately in a Decimal at any reasonable precision.  (F(10**9) has over 200 million digits!)  You need to rethink your approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting an NZEC because there are extra white spaces in the input. However, it is simple to handle them. Read the input at once and then tokenize it by white spaces.

```
import sys
tokenizedInput = sys.stdin.read().split()    # Delimited by white spaces
cases = int(tokenizedInput[0])
readAt = 1
for i in xrange(cases):
    k = 0
    n,m = map(int, tokenizedInput[readAt:readAt+2])
    sq5 = Decimal(sqrt(5))
    phi = (1 + sq5)/2                          #Refer wikipedia page for calculating fibonacci numbers
    print (int(Decimal(phi)**(m+2)/sq5 + Decimal(0.5)) - int(Decimal(phi)**(n+1)/sq5 + Decimal(0.5)))%1000000007
    readAt = readAt + 2    # Increment the position to read at by 2
```

If you submit this, you should get a TLE. As Mark Dickinson pointed out in the question comment, this is an inefficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably due to **OverflowError**

The built-in *pow()* function, i.e. ** operator, works not well as expected when the value of m in 10^9 is quite large.

```
>>> (1.1)**1000000000

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
1.1**(100000000)
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Even *math.pow()* will not work.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(1.1,1000000000)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
math.pow(1.1,1000000000)
OverflowError: math range error
```

Rather go through **O(ln m)** using Matrix method instead of *Binet's Fibonacci Formula*. As creating naive function for power in *Binet's Formula* may end up to **O(m)**

Answer (score 0):

Check my code Too:
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
#define mod 1000000007

long long result[2][2]={{1,1},{1,0}};
long long transformation[2][2]={{1,1},{1,0}};    
void matrixMul(long long a[2][2],long long b[2][2])
{
 int i,j,k;
 long long re[2][2] ={0};
 for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        for(k=0;k<2;k++) {
            re[i][j] = (re[i][j] + (a[i][k]*b[k][j])%mod ) % mod;
        }
    }
 }
 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        result[i][j]=re[i][j];
 }
}

void initialize() {
result[0][0]=result[0][1]=result[1][0]=1;
result[1][1]=0;
}
void power(int n)
{
if(n==1)
return ;
power(n/2);
matrixMul(result,result);
if(n&1)
{
    matrixMul(result,transformation);
}
}

int main()
{   
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
initialize();
long long n,m;
cin>>n>>m;
long long x,y;
if(n == 0 || n == 1) {
        x=n;
}
else {
    power(n);
    x=result[0][0]-1;
}
initialize();
if(m == 0 || m == 1) {
        x=m;
}
else {
    power(m+1);
    y=result[0][0]-1;
}
if(x>y){
    x=x-y;
}
else
    x=y-x;

cout<<((x+mod)%mod)<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```